# Rails URL helpers turning wildcard path params into query params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

#### setup

We are using Rails 4.2.10.
We have nested resource routes defined like

```ruby
resources :projects do
  resources :items, except: [:show]
  get '(:scope/(:scope2))/items/:id', to: 'items#show'
end
```

#### working as expected

Now `rake routes` yields as expected

```
...

GET /projects/:project_id(/:scope(/:scope2))/items/:id(.:format) items#show    

...
```

and calling the URL `/projects/my-project/all/my/items/2.js` correctly sets the controller params to

```
{
  "controller"=>"items", "action"=>"show", "project_id"=>"my-project",
  "id"=>"52328", "scope"=>"all", "scope2"=>"my"
}
```

#### not working as expected

We expect calling `app.project_item_path('my-project', 2, scope: 'all', scope2: 'my', format: 'js')` on the console to yield

```
/projects/my-project/all/my/items/2.js
```

but it actually yields

```
/projects/my-project/items/2.js?scope=all&scope2=my
```

Why is that the case? How can we make rails fill in the wildcard params `:scope` and `:scope2` in the positions given in the routes instead of making them query params?

### update

Similar to the proposal in the first answer, I tried

```
resources :projects do
  get '(:scope/(:scope2))/items/:id', to: 'items#show', as: :item
  resources :items, except: [:show]
end
```

While this does not result in an immediate error, now calling `app.project_item_path('my-project', 222, scope: 'all')` results in

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches 
{:action=>"show", :project_id=>"my-project", :controller=>"items",
:id=>nil, :scope=>"all", :scope2=>222} missing required keys: [:id]
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you try by adding "as" parameter to your route. For example;

```
resources :projects do
  resources :items, except: [:show]
  get '(:scope/(:scope2))/items/:id', to: 'items#show', as: :scoped_item
end
```

Then you can set your scope variables to this routes.

```
app.project_scoped_item_path('my-project', 222, scope: 'all')
```

Comment: This causes the following error: `Invalid route name, already in use: 'project_item'  (ArgumentError)`
You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming.

Comment: It mixed with default route from resources. You could use as;

`get '(:scope/(:scope2))/items/:id', to: 'items#show', as: :scoped_item`

Then in your path as: `app.project_scoped_item_path('my-project', 222, scope: 'all')`

Comment: @AlexanderPresber was my answer solved your problem?